# HTML CSS based Web page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, gtk

I want to make a web page  which looks like this :
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRqiu.png). Is there any existing theme to design a page which looks like this, if not then how should i go about creating such similar looking web page.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I fail to undestand why this is tagged "gtk" as you're doing web development...

Answer (score 0):

Create a [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) with the required number of rows and columns and in the appropriate tags write the code for input box or select dropdown or whatever element you want to be displayed. There will be no readymade templates available and this one is pretty easy to make once you get the table rows and columns right.

P.S You can also use Bootstrap to enhance the look of the table with minimum effort